# WOW64_CONTEXT in byte arrays instead of instance

Tags: c#

CONTEXT Context = new CONTEXT(); Context.ContextFlags = 0x10002;

Creating an instance of a CONTEXT structure with context flags as shown above is equal to the byte array example below:

```
int[] Context = new int[0xb3];
Context[0] = 0x10002;
```

This was the 32-bit version of CONTEXT structure. I want to do the same but for 64-bit version `WOW64_CONTEXT` as shown below.

```
CONTEXT64 Context64 = new CONTEXT64();
Context64.ContextFlags = 0x10007;
```

I tried as the example below but `Wow64GetThreadContext` failed.

```
int[] Context64 = new int[0xb3];
Context64[0] = 0x10007;

if (!Wow64GetThreadContext(PI.ThreadHandle, Context64))
    return false;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: Wow64GetThreadContext is defined like this:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool Wow64GetThreadContext(IntPtr thread, int[] context);
```

Comment: How is `Wow64GetThreadContext` defined?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Improve the error handling first, add `SetLastError=true` to the DllImport declaration and throw a Win32Exception when the function fails.  And sure, it is much more strict than GetThreadContext.  It must only be called from a 64-bit process, the target thread must belong to a 32-bit process, it must have been suspended first with Wow64SuspendThread and the context must be a WOW32_CONTEXT.  Which is at least 0xcc bytes long, your code is corrupting the GC heap right now in 32-bit mode as well.  Writing your own unmanaged debugger is not the greatest idea, it has been done.

Comment: I read that Wow64 APIs are used only when getting information about 32-bit process running on 64-bit system. I changed Context's bytes (CONTEXT32) to ``int[] Context = new int[0xcc];`` and ``Wow64GetThreadContext`` to ``GetThreadContext``. Also I set ``SetLastError = true`` and ``Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`` returned 998.